# Retrieving data from a postgresql request using angularJs

Tags: angularjs, postgresql

I'm trying to use http service, I want to retrieve data from a postgresql request, I used angular.fromJson but it's not working.

There is the request response:

[image: request response]

For example I want to retrieve only 'lat':

[image: PHP]

Comment: Server is sending extra characters `cie` before the json which makes whole response invalid json

Comment: Do you have any idea why server is sending "cie" ? Because in the query I just select "lng" and "lat" from a table named "cie"

Comment: No idea without seeing some server code.

Comment: I add php file in the question as a picture

Comment: Must have been before you commented out `echo $nametab`

Comment: Before `echo $nametab` I have `$nameTab= $_GET['nameCouche'];` to return the right name of the table in this example is `cie`

Comment: But you can't echo anything outside of the json or it makes the full response invalid. You can certainly do it to manually check response body but the json parser will fil when you do

Comment: I just noticed that when I comment `echo $nametab` I get a response [object Object]

Comment: Right..when you took screenshot it was commented and should have worked then

Comment: I still can't get the data `lng` and `lat` ...

Comment: Need to read [ask] and [mcve] and put all relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution